# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request

Tags: php

I am strugling with this code:

```
$auth = base64_encode('domain\username:password');
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy:80',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth",
    ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.codecraft.gr", false, $cxContext);

echo $sFile;
```

i keep getting the following message

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.codecraft.gr) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web P in C:\wamp\www\test17\tarantula.php on line 17

the thing is that myusername and password are correct, and i realy cant find something to help me with that ISA server :S
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A typical error that you will encounter is error 407 Proxy Authentication Required this means that the authentication has been denied because the user has no valid user account in the domain or that the password has been entered incorrectly." Microsoft ISA Troubleshooting guide. You should probably check if the user has the correct resource permissions then.

Comment: The server is running ISA server 2006, My username and password are correct , since I use them on my browser, something else is going on here any other suggestions?

Comment: i am sure the username and passwords are correct :S. Sorry i was away for some time. There is something else going on here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but have you checked resource permissions? Is your user allowed to access the ISA proxy in the OU?